# How to compare two consecutive elements in c++ list

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, find

I need to find two elements with equal fields. They should be consecutive in the same vector. I need to do it with STL method. I've tried using find or find_if but couldn't do it. Can you give me any hint, please?

My code(some parts of it):

```
class Sound {
    private:
        int notePitch, length;
    public:
        Sound(int notePitch, int length) {
            this->notePitch = notePitch;
            this->length = length;
        }
        int getPitch() {
            std::cout << "Pitch: " << this->notePitch << " length: " << this->length;
            return this->notePitch;
        }
    };
```

The actual find function:

```
std::vector<Sound>::iterator iter = masterpiece.begin();
std::vector<Sound>::iterator iterEnd = masterpiece.end();   
std::vector<Sound>::iterator it = find_if(iter, iterEnd, [](auto prev, auto next) -> bool {                 
    return prev.getPitch()  == next.getPitch(); 
});
```

The error I get is this:

```
c2678 binary '==' no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type
```

Comment: Look at `std::adjacent_find`.

Comment: That's an odd error message for this. I would have expected a two argument predicate to have tripped this code up.

Comment: Look up [strict weak ordering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) - when sorting, that's what you must implement. `return ==` is *not* the same as `return <`.

Answer (score 1):

Use adjacent_find in place of find_if. Your code should work.

```
std::vector<Sound>::iterator it = adjacent_find (iter, iterEnd, [](auto prev, auto next) -> bool {                 
    return prev.getPitch()  == next.getPitch();
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard algorithm `std::find_if` does not accept a binary predicate.

You can use the standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find` with a lambda expression.

The member function `getPitch` should be declared with the qualifier `const`. In this case you can use the function for constant objects (for example when an object of the type Sound or a vector of objects Sound is passed to a function that accepts a constant reference)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>

class Sound {
    private:
        int notePitch, length;
    public:
        Sound(int notePitch, int length) {
            this->notePitch = notePitch;
            this->length = length;
        }
        int getPitch() const {
//            std::cout << "Pitch: " << this->notePitch << " length: " << this->length;
            return this->notePitch;
        }
    };

int main( void )
{
    std::vector<Sound> masterpiece = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 5 } };

    auto it = std::adjacent_find( std::begin( masterpiece ), std::end( masterpiece ),
                                  []( const  Sound &a, const Sound &b )
                                  {
                                    return a.getPitch() == b.getPitch();
                                  } );

    if ( it != std::end( masterpiece ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Two adjacent elements are found at position " 
                  << std::distance( std::begin( masterpiece ), it )
                  << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Two adjacent elements are found\n";
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Two adjacent elements are found at position 1
```

You can the parameters of the lambda expression to write using `auto`

```
[]( const auto &a, const auto &b )
{
    return a.getPitch() == b.getPitch();
}
```

But in any case it is better to declare them as having a const referenced type because in this case neither temporary objects will be created and the lambda expression guarantees that it does not change its arguments.

Comment: Worth a short note explaining why you `const`ified `getPitch`. Long term it would probably be more useful to the Asker.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes. Why it should be const. Tested with VC++ 14.x and able to compile without const qualifier. Please provide an explanation

Comment: @SolidMercury You can compile without const because your vector is not constant and maybe you declared the parameters of the lambda expression as a non constant referenced types or as a non referenced type.